# Cucumber test failed : All but one formatter must use --out, only one can print to each stream (or STDOUT)

Tags: ruby, cucumber

> Argument to bundle: [exec, cucumber, -p, full_pca, -t, ~@calendar_on, -t, ~@productCompare_off, -t, ~@newMap_off, -t, ~@independentListings_off, -t, ~@search.result.broaden.search_off, -t, ~@consumer.adtarget_on, -t, ~@yearly.median.price_on, -t, ~@content.strategy_on, -t, ~@legal.pages_on, -t, ~@mycommercial.api.integration_on, -t, ~@dashboard.new.saved.properties_off, -t, ~@business.decommission_on, -t, ~@agentprofiles.pdplinks_off, -t, ~@rui.schoolInformation_off, -t, ~@suggest.resiAgentApiSearch_off, -t, ~@omniture.satellite_off, --format, junit, --out, build/test-data]
>
> error 24-Sep-2015 13:27:17    All but one formatter must use --out, only one can print to each stream (or STDOUT) (RuntimeError)
>
> error 24-Sep-2015 13:27:17    /opt/atlassian/bamboo/.gem/ruby/2.2.3/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/options.rb:292:in `check_formatter_stream_conflicts'
>
> error 24-Sep-2015 13:27:17    /opt/atlassian/bamboo/.gem/ruby/2.2.3/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/options.rb:274:in `parse!'
>
> error 24-Sep-2015 13:27:17    /opt/atlassian/bamboo/.gem/ruby/2.2.3/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/options.rb:55:in `parse'

Anyone know what happened?

Comment: default: -r features/support -r features/step_definitions -t ~@quarantine -t ~@wip --format pretty --format html -o build/reports/cuke.html
smoke: -r features/support -r features/step_definitions  --format pretty --format html -o build/reports/cuke.html features/smoke
quick: -r features/support -r features/step_definitions  --format pretty --format html -o build/reports/cuke.html -t

Comment: `rm -rf cucumber.yml` should help. It looks like some script appends the info there (see these multiple `--format pretty`?—they cause an error.)